# Python Can't Find Wolframalpha Module

Tags: python, pip

I'm tyring to import wolfamalpha into my code but it gives a error saying:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wolframalpha'
```

I tried installing it with `pip install wolframalpha`, but it still doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
import wolframalpha

client = wolframalpha.Client('*************')
```

Comment: Do you have installed this module? If no, use this ```pip install wolframalpha``` to download and install wolframalpha 4.1.1

Comment: Yes I did that, but it still doesn't work. Do you know anything else I can try?

Comment: can you give up the output of typing `which pip`, and `which python` in the terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your python file, are you sure that you are using the correct python interpreter that you performed the pip install wolframalpha to? It sounds like you may have multiple versions of python on your machine and there is a mismatch. If you are using VSCode, it is easy to see which interpreter is running on the bottom of the screen, which may help you debug the issue.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jory if this answer provided the solution for you, accept it please using the grey checkmark on the left of it